# Distribution function for a fair cube

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

I have a fair cube with n-sides (1,...,n). I have a random variable R which is the maximum number of the cube that will appear after dicing the cube k-times.

What is the distribution function of R?

I dont know how to get the function. I already know that the probability of a fair cube is 1/n.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: could it be s^k/n^k with s from 1...k?

Comment: I'm confused. If you have a cube, why does it have $n$ sides? Do you mean to say it has other than 6 sides? And if so, how is it still a cube?  And what does dicing your cube involve? Making it smaller with an onion nicer dicer plus, or the kitchen super splicer?

Answer (score 1):

For every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, each result is at most $i$ with probability $\frac{i}n$ hence, by independence,
$$P(R\leqslant i)=\left(\tfrac{i}n\right)^k.
$$
Thus, for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$,
$$P(R=i)=\left(\tfrac{i}n\right)^k-\left(\tfrac{i-1}n\right)^k.$$